# Fill rows by default values if limit for data columns is defined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to fill rows by  default value `=1` in DataFrame based on information in `Start` and `Finish` columns.
So, limit for filling separated columns in row is defined based on `['Start', 'Finish']`.

DataFrame, `df1` is:

```
ID  Car       Jan17     Jun18  Dec18  Apr19   Start   Finish                           
0   Nissan     0.0       1.7    3.7    0.0    Jun18   Dec18   
1   Porsche    10.0      0.0    2.8    3.5    Jan17   Apr19 
2   Golf       0.0       1.7    3.0    2.0    Jun18   Apr19 
3   Toyota     1.0       0.0    3.0    5.2    Jan17   Apr19 
4   Mazda      0.0       0.0    3.0    4.2    Dec18   Apr19
5   Mercedes   0.0       0.0    0.0    7.2    Apr19   Apr19
6   Passat     0.0       3.0    0.0    0.0    Jun18   Jun18
```

For instance, if there is a row #0:
`Start = Jun18`  and   `Finish = Dec18`.

Values in row#0 should be filled by  `1` for columns, started from `Jun18` till to `Dec18`.

I tried to use `numpy.sign()` function, but there is wrong result in case, if `0.0` is between of two non-zero values.

Expected result is `df2`:

```
ID  Car       Jan17     Jun18  Dec18  Apr19   Start   Finish                           
0   Nissan     0.0       1.0    1.0    0.0    Jun18   Dec18   
1   Porsche    1.0       1.0    1.0    1.0    Jan17   Apr19 
2   Golf       0.0       1.0    1.0    1.0    Jun18   Apr19 
3   Toyota     1.0       1.0    1.0    1.0    Jan17   Apr19 
4   Mazda      0.0       0.0    1.0    1.0    Dec18   Apr19
5   Mercedes   0.0       0.0    0.0    1.0    Apr19   Apr19
6   Passat     0.0       1.0    0.0    0.0    Jun18   Jun18
```

Comment: For row #3, not sure I understand if Jun18 should be 1 or 0?

Comment: @Ben.T, for row#3 ```Jun18``` should be in ```1```, because it was temporary broke, and after ```0``` the process was continued in the ```Dec18```. That's why there is an issue with usage ```numpy.sign()``` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `get_dummies` + `interpolate`

This requires your columns to be sorted in time order, and for Start and Finish to ideally always exist in the column names.

```
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'Car', 'Start', 'Finish'])

s1 = (pd.get_dummies(df.index.get_level_values('Start'))
        .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
        .replace(0, np.NaN))
s2 = (pd.get_dummies(df.index.get_level_values('Finish'))
        .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
        .replace(0, np.NaN))

res = s1.combine_first(s2).interpolate(axis=1, limit_area='inside').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
res.index = df.index
res = res.reset_index()
```

#### Output `res`:

```
   ID       Car  Start Finish  Jan17  Jun18  Dec18  Apr19
0   0    Nissan  Jun18  Dec18      0      1      1      0
1   1   Porsche  Jan17  Apr19      1      1      1      1
2   2      Golf  Jun18  Apr19      0      1      1      1
3   3    Toyota  Jan17  Apr19      1      1      1      1
4   4     Mazda  Dec18  Apr19      0      0      1      1
5   5  Mercedes  Apr19  Apr19      0      0      0      1
6   6    Passat  Jun18  Jun18      0      1      0      0
```

---

In the case where `Start` and `Finish` were already derived from the data itself (seems to be the first and last non-zero columns), you can skip all of the dummies and use `where` instead on the original DataFrame.

```
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'Car', 'Start', 'Finish'])
res = (df.where(df.ne(0))
         .clip(1,1)
         .interpolate(axis=1, limit_area='inside')
         .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
         .reset_index())
```

Comment: Now, that is a cool solution. +1  I wouldn't used interpolate but pd.date_range.  Great solution. I think this is better that my first thoughts.

Comment: Yeah, I think the "safer" alternative is to convert everything to `datetime` that way you can deal with missing dates properly. But it seems like `Start` and `Finish` may be derived from the data to begin with, in which case this will work, albeit slowly because of the interpolate.

Comment: @ALollz, thanks a lot for your code and idea. That's what I need:) Thanks.

Comment: @ALollz, how can I fix the case when start and Date are the same in the middle of date_period, as like:    ```5   Mercedes   0.0       0.0    7.2    0.0    Apr19   Apr19```. So, the result should be: ```5   Mercedes   0.0       0.0    1.0    0.0    Dec18    Dec18 ```. But actual is: ```5   Mercedes   0.0       0.0    1.0    1.0    Dec18    Apr19 ```

Comment: @ALollz, yes, you are right I need to fill between the start and end dates and also keep anything that was non-zero to ```1```. Now I have the problem that when ```Start``` and ```Finish``` are the same, code returns interpolation for the ```Start``` till to the last existing column, but it should be replace only one value to 1 and stop. For example, I added line#6 in the question.. And in this case ```3.0``` should be replace to 1 only for ```Jun18``` column and don't continue to ```Apr19``` column. Thanks

Comment: @Cindy good catch. Please see the update. We need to add the `limit_area='inside'` argument to the interpolation

Comment: @ALollz, yes, after update it works as expected. Thanks a lot!